# php find a substring only if it's not part of another substring

Tags: php, string, substring

I know how to find substrings using strpos, but I want to return True only if the letter t appears in a string, but not if that t is followed by "he".  For example...
`$str="The lion and dog are hungry"`
The result would be `Does not contain t` because the only t in the string was part of the word "The". 
 `$str="Their bedroom is ugly"` should also return false because "Their" starts with T H E and there's not other t in the string.
`$str="The cat and the dog are hungry"` would result in `Yes, this string contains a t` because there's a t in CAT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a negative lookbehind regex:

```
/t(?!h(?:e|is))/i
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oU4hG9/2)

**Pattern details**:

- `t` - a literal char `t`
- `(?!h(?:e|is))` - a negative lookbehind that checks if its pattern matches the string after the current location and failing the match (returning false) if the match occurs:

  - `h` - a literal `h`
  - `(?:e|is)` - either `e` or `is` (the `(?:...|...)` is a non-capturing group that does not keep submatches in the memory containing a `|` alternation operator)
- `/i` - case insensitive modifier making the regex match in a case insensitive way.

Basically, this is a more efficient version of a `t(?!he|his)` regex (`t` not followed with `he` or `his`).

[PHP demo](http://ideone.com/qz97ia):

```
$re = '/t(?!h(?:e|is))/i';

if (preg_match($re,'The cat and the dog are hungry'))
    echo 'true';
else
    echo 'false';
```

Comment: /t(?!he)(?!his)/i  becuase the asker update his question in the replies

Comment: @Mostafa: Good, I adjusted the pattern and the demo links are updated.

Comment: Very good, detailed answer.  I actually went with the less efficient `t(?!he|his)`  That works fine for me and it's easy to understand.

Comment: With regexps, the best practice is to make sure they match *linearly*, the previous subpattern should not match at the same location as the next subpattern. Thus, it is not a good idea to use alternative branches starting with the same character(s). I agree in this concrete case that won't make much difference in performance, but if you think of expanding the pattern, or put it into a much longer pattern, you should bear this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$a = 'Their bedroom is ugly';

if (preg_match('/t(?!he)(?!his)/i',$a))
    echo 'true';
else
    echo 'false';
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. One more question... I'm not good with regex, How would I add another condition to it, for example, if I didn't want to include T H E or T H I  So `The boy and this girl` would result in false because the only T's are in The and This.

Comment: `/t[^the]/` matches a `t` that is followed with 1 char other than `t`, `h`, or `e`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think it will not return true if the letter T in the end of the text, Can you try to update the answer

Comment: You can add an 'i' after the last '/' to make the regex case insensitive. You could also replace 't' with a character class '[tT]' so it will match either 't' or 'T', you can also use an or '|' like this 't|T'

Comment: Using the `/i` modifier is the preferred way, I think. Also, `(?!he)(?!his)` looks too verbose, the same effect is achieved with alternation inside the lookahead: `(?!he|his)`, see my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use strpos to check to see if there's an 'he' after all the 't's you find:

```
<?php
$offest = 0;
$string = "the t the";
$result = 'No, this string does not contain t';
while ($pos1 = strpos($string,'t', $offset)) {
    if ($pos2 = strpos($string,'the',$offset) {
        if ($pos1 != $pos2) {
            $result = 'Yes, this string contains t';
        } else {
            $offset = pos1;
        }
    } else {
        $result = 'Yes, this string contains t';
    }
}
echo $result;
```

but that's not the most efficient way to do it. IMHO the best thing to do would be to use a [Regex](http://php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php)

```
$string = "the t the";
$result = 'no';
if (preg_match('/[tT][^Hh]/')) {
    $result = 'yes';
}
```

You can also use [negative lookahead](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php) (a personal favorite technique):

```
$string = "the t the";
$result = 'no';
if (preg_match('/t(?!he)/i')) {
    $result = 'yes';
}
```